# Query Firestore for documents that satisfy AND condition

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Assuming I have documents in the Firestore in the following format:

```
{
    'field1': ['v1', 'v2', 'v3'],
    'field2': ['v5', 'v6']
}
```

I want to query for the documents where the `field1` contains a value from the given values, and the `field2` contains a given value. I want to perform an AND operation where I specify these conditions in a single query only and get all the valid documents. Following is what I tried:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(COLLECTION)
        .where("field1", arrayContainsAny: ['v1', 'v2'])
        .where('field2', arrayContains: 'v1')
        .get();
```

But I got an exception:

[image]

So Is there any way to combine these to make a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is there any way to combine these to make a query?

No, you cannot combine `arrayContainsAny` and `arrayContains` in the same query. According to the official documentation regarding [array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership):

> You can use at most one `array-contains` clause per disjunction (or group). You **can't** combine `array-contains` with `array-contains-any` in the same disjunction.

To solve this, you should use one of the conditions in the query and filter the rest of the results on the client.

Answer (score 1):

If the two Arrays are not too large ([Maximum size for a document is 1 MiB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields)) you could create a new field that combines both Arrays as follows:

```
const field1 = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3'],
    field2 = ['v5', 'v6'],
    combinedField = [];

field1.forEach(elemArray1 => {
  field2.forEach(elemArray2 => {
    combinedField.push('${elemArray1}_${elemArray2}');
  });
});

// combinedField = ['v1_v5', 'v1_v6', 'v2_v5', 'v2_v6', 'v3_v5', 'v3_v6']
```

and then use the following query:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(COLLECTION)
        .where("combinedField", arrayContainsAny: ['v1_v5', 'v2_v5'])
        .get();
```

Note that the arrays values should not contain the separator, `_` in this example.